# Multi-threading issue in Julia

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I'm trying parallelise some bits of a code but I do not understand why the following functions main1() and main2() give different results using Julia's multi-threading:

```
a = rand(4,4);b = rand(4,4);c = rand(4,4);d = rand(4,4)

function main1(a,b,c,d)
    L = zeros(2,2,16)
    FF = zeros(2,2,16)
    FT = zeros(2,2,16)
    F = Array{Float32}(undef,2,2)
    # L = Array{Array{Float32, 1}, 4}

    for i = 1:4
        for j = 1:4
            ic = i + j*(i-1)
            F[1,1] = a[i,j]
            F[1,2] = b[i,j]
            F[2,1] = c[i,j]
            F[2,2] = d[i,j]
            L[:,:,ic] .= F * F'
            FF[:,:,ic] .= F
            FT[:,:,ic] .= F'
        end
    end
    return L,FF,FT
end

function main2(a,b,c,d)

    L  = zeros(2,2,16)
    FF = zeros(2,2,16)
    FT = zeros(2,2,16)
    F  = Array{Float32}(undef,2,2)
    # L = Array{Array{Float32, 1}, 4}

    Threads.@threads for i = 1:4
        Threads.@threads for j = 1:4
            ic = i + j*(i-1)
            F[1,1] = a[i,j]
            F[1,2] = b[i,j]
            F[2,1] = c[i,j]
            F[2,2] = d[i,j]
            L[:,:,ic] .= F * F'
            FF[:,:,ic] .= F
            FT[:,:,ic] .= F'
        end
    end
    return L,FF,FT
end
```

How could the parallelisation of main1() be properly fixed?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot nest `@threads` loops so normally you should do:

```
Threads.@threads for u in vec(CartesianIndices((4,4)))
    i,j = u.I
    # your code goes here
end
```

However, in your code you get the same `ic` value for different pair of values of `(i,j)`. In the `main1` you are overwriting the same parts of `L`, `FF`, `FT` many times which is an obvious bug. Multi-threading will change the order the data is overwritten so it will yields different results. In conclusion, first fix `main1` and than parallelize it.